# Magento 1.9 : image quality looks dull after resize

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, image-quality

I have an issue when I resize magento image then its looks dull compare with orignal image.

for More you check attached image.

I have also try these extension but not get good results

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks

I have tried these solution but not get success.

[Disable magento's compression of product images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69652/disable-magentos-compression-of-product-images)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384678/magento-resize-image-quality-dirty-white-background

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can refer given link for image quality. This for magento 1.9 only.

[How display product Image in best quality](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82928/how-display-product-image-in-best-quality)

Comment: I have tried this two solution to. but not get success, please check my question before answering.